# context.Database.SqlQuery not returning list of objects i declare

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some code that calls `GetSQLUser`(defined in the code below)... If I put a breakpoint on `var result`, the result is not as I expected (a SqlUserInfo object... would be nice).

```
public class Whatever
{
    public void GetSQLUser()
    {
        var result = this.context.Database.SqlQuery<SQLUserInfo>("SELECT SYSTEM_USER AS UserID");
    }
}

public class SQLUserInfo
{
    string UserID { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
var result = this.context.Database.SqlQuery<SQLUserInfo>("SELECT SYSTEM_USER AS UserID");
```

to

```
var result = this.context.Database.SqlQuery<SQLUserInfo>("SELECT SYSTEM_USER AS UserID").First();
```